# Is it possible put two ko.applyBindings() in the same function?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I've to put two `ko.applyBindings();` in the same function but the system turn me back a run-time error.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in the same function", but yes it's _possible_ to do so, for certain use cases.

Comment: Can you showme an exemple for a list and an array?

Comment: It's more a case of wondering _why_ you think you need to call it twice - what are you actually trying to do?  It's usually not necessary.

Comment: So how do you manage a list and an array in the same function?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - please [edit] your post to show an example, even better you could create a [mcve] either here using the Stack Snippets feature (the button with `<>` on it) or over on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you create a `viewModel` object and then call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` once, like this:

```
var viewModel = {
  personName: ko.observable('Bob'),
  personAge: ko.observable(123)
};

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

Maybe this is what you're looking?

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example, `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))`. This restricts the activation to the element with ID `someElementId` and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

From the documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

As for your comment about managing a list and an array, I'm not sure what you mean. They sound like the same thing to me. Knockout has [observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) that you can use.

Comment: A list compare out from the foreach and the array into the foreach

Comment: I've solved putting the list in the array and calling it with myArray()[0].nemeOfTheElement